# Is there a way to change the stub of existing connector?

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm creating a new jsPlumb connect. I'm setting up a connector "stub" value to 30. How to change this value "live" after drawing the diagram without re-declaration whole connect again? 
For example - a button that increases the "stub" by 10px without newConnect  re-declaration. Is there a setter for this or something?

```
newConnect = j.connect({
          source: someSource,
          target: smoeTarget,
          anchors: ["Right", "Right"],
          connector: ["Flowchart",{stub: 30} ],
          endpoint: "Rectangle",
          detachable: false,
          overlays: [
            [ "Arrow", { foldback:0.2 }]
          ]

        });
```